# How do I properly use var[0] interpretation

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, syntax

I'm new to Python and trying to make a Pig Latin Translator. My situation is that the "type" of Pig Latin you use is dependent on where a vowel and/or consonant is at the begging of the word. This causes me to use stuff like "my_var[0] = new_var". My problem is I'm trying to interpret if a variable from a raw input is contains certain string characters, like "a", "x", etc. If anyone could correct my code, as well, that would be awesome! Thanks for your help in the advance :) !

```
print "Hello. Welcome to the Pig Latin translator! :)"# Welcome MSG
eng = raw_input("Please enter in a word in English to translate to Pig Latin.")#Asking the user to input something
if eng[0] == "a" + "b"+"c" :# I'm say if the first letter equals a constant.
```

Comment: `eng[0]` is a single character. Will never equal `'abc'`

Comment: or you might want this actually? `if eng[0] == "a" or eng[0] == "b" or eng[0]=="c" : ...`

Comment: Okay, I just reliazed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
first = eng[0]
rest = eng[1:]
if first in "aeiou":
    # is a vowel 
else:
    # not a vowel, not necessarily a consonant
```